# Not able to transform and load from ADLS(csv) to Dedicated SQL Pool by using Azure Synapse's Dataflow

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am trying to transform data from ADLS by using Azure Synapse's Dataflow and store it in a table in Dedicated SQL Pool.

I created a Dataset 'UserSinkDataset' pointing to this table in Dedicated SQL Pool.
[image]

This 'UserSinkDataset' is not visible in sink dataset of dataflow
[image]

There is no option to create a dataset pointing to Dedicated pool from dataflow
[image]

Could someone help me understand why is it not being shown in the dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to create a dataset referring to dedicated SQL pool instead it provides Azure Synapse Analytics. That is why it is not showing the `UserSinkDataset` (Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL pool) in the dropdown. So, you can use Azure Synapse Analytics option to point to the table in dedicated SQL pool and create your dataset.

You can follow the steps given below.

- Once you reach the sink step, click on new.
  [image]
- Browse for Azure Synapse Analytics and continue.
  [image]
- Create a new linked service by clicking on new.
  [image]
- Specify your workspace, dedicated SQL pool (the one you want to point to) and authentication for the synapse workspace. Test the connection and create the linked service.
- After creating the linked service, you can select dbo.SFUser from your SQL pool and click ok.
  [image]
- Now you can go ahead and set the rest of the properties for sink.

You can also create ‘UserSinkDataset’ by choosing azure synapse analytics instead of azure synapse dedicated SQL pool before creating dataflow. This way the dataset created will appear in the dropdown list on sink dataset property.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks for step-by-step solution. But why does Dedicate Pool show up in Copy activity's dataset but not in Dataflow's dataset?